# Export all grid pages to pdf in kendo ui not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

```
<style>
        /*
            Use the DejaVu Sans font for display and embedding in the PDF file.
            The standard PDF fonts have no support for Unicode characters.
        */
        .k-grid {
            font-family: "DejaVu Sans", "Arial", sans-serif;
        }

        /* Hide the Grid header and pager during export */
        .k-pdf-export .k-grid-toolbar,
        .k-pdf-export .k-pager-wrap {
            display: none !important;
        }
</style>

@section pageBody {
        @using (Html.BeginForm("IndexListPage", "AccntGroup", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <!-- Query Panel -->
            <div id="queryPanel" class="containerDiv100">
                <table class="table-thinborder100">
                    <tr>
                        <!-- Showing title of the page-->
                        <td class="ob-pagetitle">
                            <span>@ViewBag.Title</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div style="float:right;margin-right:13px">
                    @(Html.Kendo().Button()
                                  .Name("Back")
                                  .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "width100", style = "float:right", type = "Button" })
                                  .Content("Back to List Page")
                                  .Events(e => e.Click("Back"))
                    )
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>

            </div>
            <div id="queryResult" class="containerDiv100">
                <div id="DIV_Line05" class="colLine" style="float: right">
                    <div id="DIV_Grid" class="col100">
                        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<AccntGroupModel>()
                            .Name("KendoGrid1")
                            .Columns(columns =>
                            {
                                // Creating a column displays as hyperlink
                                columns.Bound(m => m.AccntGroupName).Filterable(true).Title("Account Group Name").Width("30%").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "font-size:x-small" });
                                columns.Bound(m => m.AccntGroupCode).Filterable(true).Title("Code").Width("20%").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "font-size:x-small" });
                                columns.Bound(m => m.V_AccntGroupType).Filterable(true).Title("Type").Width("20%").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "font-size:x-small" });
                               columns.Bound(m => m.V_AccntGroupSubTypeLabel).Filterable(true).Title("Sub Type").Width("20%").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "font-size:x-small" });
                            })
                            .ToolBar(tools => tools.Pdf())
                            .Pdf(pdf => pdf
                                .AllPages()
                                .Title("Bizsense Solutions Pvt. Ltd. ")
                                .FileName("Kendo UI Grid Export.pdf")
                                .ProxyURL(Url.Action("Pdf_Export_Save", "AccntGroup"))
                            )
                            .Pageable()
                            .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "width100" })
                            .Scrollable(config => config.Enabled(true))        
                            .Sortable()        
                            .DataSource(source => source
                            .Ajax()
                            .PageSize(10)            
                            .Model(model =>
                            {
                               model.Id(m => m.AccntGroupId);
                            })
                            .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "AccntGroup", new { area = "ListPage" }))
                        )
                     )
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#KendoGrid1").kendoGrid({
                    pageSize: 10,
                    height: 350,         
                });
            });
            function Back()
            {
                var ActionUrl = "@Url.Action("ListPageMenuIndex", "Menu", new { area = "Menu" })"
                $.ajax({
                    url: ActionUrl,
                    success: function (result) {
                        window.location.href="@Url.Action("ListPageMenuIndex", "Menu", new { area = "Menu" })"
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Pdf_Export_Save(string contentType, string base64, string fileName)
{
    var fileContents = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
    return File(fileContents, contentType, fileName);
}
```

ALL PAGES NOT GETTING EXPORTED TO PDF.
The way it works for excel.. allpages() is not working for pdf. people suggested to add that style part.. but still it is not working..
neither the title is getting set..
i have just updates my telerik.. do i need to add any references or scripts or links?

Comment: Make sure you are using Kendo.2015.1.408 or later. I had issues with the built-in exporting prior to that.  Also, try removing the ProxyURL configuration, and try with a browser that doesn't need that to see if maybe that is the issue.

Comment: @RobinGiltner i tried it all... nothing is working